# debase LoadError when debugging in RubyMine with ruby 2.0.0 on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, debugging, ide, osx-mavericks, rubymine

After upgrading to OS X Mavericks (10.9.2), my RubyMine can no longer debug. It quits unexpectedly with the following error:

Testing started at 1:37 PM ...
/Users/vinny.ly/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.23.beta1/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:8:in `require': cannot load such file -- debase (LoadError)

I have the following Ruby and gems

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0]

$ gem list debugger
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.4)

$ gem list ruby-debug-ide
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.23.beta1, 0.4.22)

$ gem list debase
debase (0.0.9)
```

I am running RubyMine 6.3. I have tried reverting to previous versions 6.0.3 and 5.4.3 but I get the same error.

I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing the gems, which didn't help.

Answer (score 7):

I managed to fix this problem by upgrading ruby-debug-ide from 0.4.23beta to 0.4.23:  `gem install ruby-debug-ide` (outside of your project directory), then restart RubyMine.

Comment: Thanks! How you figure out it?

Answer (score 2):

Just fixed this by messing about with the suggestions here (nothing worked), then going to the `Ruby SDK and Gems` settings in Rubymine and switching from the `global (ruby-2.1.4)` to the `RVM: ruby-2.1.4` option above it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this problem with RubyMine 6.3.3 and Ruby 2.1.2. That version of RubyMine installs the same gem versions except that debugger-ruby_core_source is now at 1.3.5.

If you're not on RM 6.3.3, try upgrading. I've seen RM bugfix upgrades fix debug gem installation failures.

Comment: Im on RubyMine 6.3.3 and I am getting the same error. Its driving me a little nuts haha! I have tried and read all that I can about this issue and Im nowhere. Any other solutions to his?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like RubyMine 6.3.3 (and even 7.0.2) will have this problem if you are using ruby version 2.0.0.  Try using a newer version of ruby instead.

Install newer ruby version using the rvm and set it to the default.

e.g.

```
rvm install 2.1.1
rvm --default use 2.1.1
```

Then in your project, modify your Gemfile to use 2.1.1:

```
ruby '2.1.1'
```

And then reinstall your gem bundle for the project:

```
gem install bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem appeared with Ruby 2.2.2. A full update to ruby-debug-ide 0.4.28 solved the problem with Rubymine.

Answer (score 0):

Open RubyMine

1. Click Preferences
2. Click Languages  & Frameworks
3. Click Ruby SDK and Gems

Then Change to appropriate version of ruby for your project￼

Answer (score 0):

In my case I upgraded Ruby from 2.4.1 to 2.4.4 and got this error when trying to run

```
rails server
```

and nothing previously mentioned on this article worked. After googling I found this bug report: https://github.com/ruby-debug/ruby-debug-ide/issues/71
where they suggest to add require: false to Gemfile:

```
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide', require: false
```

After this it started to work. However, the debugging doesn't work after this unless you set require back to true.